# Questão vetor portugol

Tags: portugol

Duas questoes sobre vetores e matrizes.
1_Dado um vetor qualquer com 100 números inteiros, faça um módulo que informa se há ou não
números repetidos nesse vetor.

Algoritmo "Repetição no vetor"

```
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
vet : vetor [1..10] de inteiro
i,j, aux: inteiro
rep: inteiro

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
para i de 1 ate 10 faca
leia (vet[i])
fimpara

para i de 1 ate 9 faca
para j de i ate 10 faca
     se vet[j] < vet[i] entao
        aux <- vet[j]
        vet[j] <- vet[i]
        vet[i]<- aux
     fimse
fimpara
fimpara
para i de 1 ate 10 faca
escreva (vet[i])
fimpara
rep<- (vet[1])
 para i de 1 ate 10 faca
      se (vet[i] = rep) entao
         escreva ("O numero", rep," está repetido.")
      fimse
 fimpara

Fimalgoritmo
```

// nesse algoritmo infelizmente ele so aponta se tiver apenas 1 numero repetido.

2_Dado um vetor de 20 números reais e uma matriz 20x20 de números reais, informe quais
linhas e colunas são iguais ao vetor, esteja ele na ordem dada ou em ordem inversa. Assuma
que obrigatoriamente há uma linha ou coluna igual ao vetor na matriz.

Comment: O que já tentou fazer? Seria interessante você adicionar sua tentativa na pegunta, clicando em [edit]

Comment: ok, foi mal, sou novo aqui :)

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser ver a quantidade de números repetidos, será necessário fazer uma variável `cont`.

Para armazenar os números repetidos pode fazer um vetor extra e armazena-los lá.

Essa parte:

```
    se vet[j] < vet[i] entao
    aux <- vet[j]
    vet[j] <- vet[i]
    vet[i]<- aux
    fimse
```

(não precisa fazer ordenação apenas ver se repete)

Cria uma variável k.

```
    k:inteiro
    vet2 : vetor [1..10] de inteiro

    k<-1
    para i de 1 ate 10 faca
    para j de 1 ate 10 faca
    se vet[j] = vet[i] entao
    vet2[k]<-vet[j]
    k=k+1

   fimse
   fimpara
   fimpara
    //depois realiza um laço para escrever o vetor k na qual
```